# Removing Windows Update's nagging dialogue box

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I've found how to stop the automatic restart for Windows Update on Windows 7 Home Premium using regedit, but I still get a dialogue box nagging me every four hours to restart my computer.
Is there any way to remove this dialogue, or at least extend the time between nags? (Or better yet, replace it with a one-off nag, and maybe just leave an icon the system tray as a reminder?)

Comment: You could just tell windows update to not automatically install updates. It would then tell you there were updates available, but not actually install them until you were ready.

Comment: No, I don't want to be punished with makework just because I want to be able to choose when I restart my computer.

Answer (score 2):

Run Registry Editor (*regedit*), navigate to the following key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update
```

and look for a value labeled *ForcedReboot*.

If it's present, just right-click it, select Modify, and set Value data to 0. You're done!

[Source](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57366233-285/how-to-disable-reboot-reminders-in-windows/).